# Getting column names in a doctrine2 entity

Tags: doctrine-orm

How to get the names of all columns in a doctrine entity?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

As described in the documentation for [ClassMetadataInfo](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/class-Doctrine.ORM.Mapping.ClassMetadataInfo.html#_getColumnNames) you can use the `getColumnNames` method:

```
$em->getClassMetadata('Entities\MyEntity')->getColumnNames();
```

Comment: That's not the column name, it's the property name.. should be ->getColumnNames() instead

Comment: This answer is not complete you dont have the foreign key and the discriminator. see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31827554/symfony-getting-all-field-names-from-database-table/42901920#42901920