# Symfony getting all field names from database table

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to get all database table field names. I've already tried getting that using `ClassMetadata` unfortunately `getColumnNames()` doesn't return relational field names. and method `getAssociationNames()` returns names of entity properties which are not the same names and also might include fields that doesn't really exist in database when using `oneToMany` relations.

As people mentioned that this may be duplicate. It's not. [Getting column names in a doctrine2 entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825812/getting-column-names-in-a-doctrine2-entity) which might be a similar problem but `getFieldNames` method  doesn't return field names which has relations to other entities.

So how do I get All column names from database table?

Comment: Are you looking for cross platform solution or some DBMS specific?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting column names in a doctrine2 entity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825812/getting-column-names-in-a-doctrine2-entity)

Comment: As I mentioned in my question it doesn't get everything I need. It's not a duplicate. I saw that question and it does not solve my problem

Comment: Cross platform solution would be ideal. otherwise MySQL would work for now

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I solved this with this code :

```
$class = $this->em->getClassMetadata('Entity');
    $fields = [];
    if (!empty($class->discriminatorColumn)) {
        $fields[] = $class->discriminatorColumn['name'];
    }
    $fields = array_merge($class->getColumnNames(), $fields);
    foreach ($fields as $index => $field) {
        if ($class->isInheritedField($field)) {
            unset($fields[$index]);
        }
    }
    foreach ($class->getAssociationMappings() as $name => $relation) {
        if (!$class->isInheritedAssociation($name)){
            foreach ($relation['joinColumns'] as $joinColumn) {
                $fields[] = $joinColumn['name'];
            }
        }
    }
    return $fields;
```

Comment: Perhaps you should check that 'joinColumns' key really exists in $relation. 
There are cases where it's doesn't.

Comment: Not sure it is a super good idea to delete elements of an array while you are iterating over it....

Answer (score 4):

In Doctrine the DBAL component is made to handle database-level tasks. It is also able to list all columns of a database table. The DBAL component operates on the database level wich means it does **not** look at any entity metadata. Assuming you have an EntityManager instance, you can get the column names like this:

```
// $em is your Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager instance
$schemaManager = $em->getConnection()->getSchemaManager();
// array of Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Column
$columns = $schemaManager->listTableColumns($tableName);

$columnNames = [];
foreach($columns as $column){
    $columnNames[] = $column->getName();
}
// $columnNames contains all column names
```

The documentation for the schema manager can be found here:
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.9/reference/schema-manager.html#schema-manager

Comment: Works fine - does contain the relation column name.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using raw sql query. In my case as I was needing all the data from the table for the data export I used the query `"SELECT * FROM $tableName"` and then I used `array_keys` function with the first result row. In case I need to get entity field names representing that column you can use:

```
$entityManager->getClassMetadata->getFieldForColumn($column);
```

It doesn't take arguments as array so I have to foreach all db column names with this function but with this

Comment: Well, that's a rather poor solution. First, native SQL is really bad, especially to get meta information. Second, if you really want to do native SQL, why do you load the *entire* table? Ever heard of `LIMIT`? Not to mention `SHOW COLUMNS`.

Comment: As I said I was needing all the data anyway for export. and I don't see any reason why native SQL should be bad in this case.